# How can I get HTML fields to stay together on one line when displayed in a browser?

Tags: html

I am putting fields to capture each part of a US Social Security Number on a web page.  I want them to stay together, separated by a space-dash-space.  However, the second field is always separated by a large space from the first (the third field is displaying correctly near the second).  I have tried all sorts of things and nothing that I tried helps.  I would appreciate any help I can get on getting this to look right in the browser.

The HTML code is as follows (this is embedded in a table with the rest of the address information above it):

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="ssn">Social Security Number:<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></td>
    <td>
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox" id="agentSSN1" maxlength="3" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the first three numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
    </td>
    <td><span >-</span></td>
    <td>
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox"  id="agentSSN2" maxlength="2" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the middle two numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
    </td>
    <td><span >-</span></td>
    <td>
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox"  id="agentSSN3" maxlength="4"  onblur="setSSN()" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the last four numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
    </td>
    <td> 
        <form:hidden id="ssn" name="ssn" path="ssn" cssClass="txtbox" maxlength="9" onkeyup="fmtssn();" />  
    </td>                               
</tr>
```

I have also tried using ampersand nbsp; dash ampersand nbsp;" instead of span -
 /span.

Can anyone help me with this?   Thank you!

Comment: can you make a demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vnfyfs9h/ what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the fields to be on separate table cells?

That complicates the layout because you have to deal not only with input layout but with table layout also.

I would try to make a single cell using colspan. At the end all the inputs and dashes are semantically part of the same 'field'.

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="ssn">Social Security Number:<span style="color: red;">*</span></label></td>
    <td colspan="5">
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox" id="agentSSN1" maxlength="3" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the first three numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
        <span >-</span></td>
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox"  id="agentSSN2" maxlength="2" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the middle two numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
        <span >-</span>
        <form:input type="password" path="" class="txtbox"  id="agentSSN3" maxlength="4"  onblur="setSSN()" cssStyle=" width : 76px;" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter the last four numbers of your Social Security number." style="-moz-appearance:textfield;"/>
        <form:hidden id="ssn" name="ssn" path="ssn" cssClass="txtbox" maxlength="9" onkeyup="fmtssn();" />  
    </td>                               
</tr>
```